# Are JSF 2.2 Faces Flows supported in PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, faces-flow

I am testing JSF 2.2 Faces flows in a PrimeFaces application and when I replace h:button with p:button the link stops working.
In JSF 2.2 you can specify, for example, the flow_id in the "outcome" of a h:button. This seems not to work in PF . The exception I'm getting is:

```
[ERROR   ] SRVE0315E: An exception occurred: java.lang.Throwable: javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4898)
   at [internal classes]
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:230)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
   at [internal classes]
   at com.servengine.servlet.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:44)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
   at [internal classes]
   at com.servengine.servlet.ServengineWebFilter.doFilter(ServengineWebFilter.java:136)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
   ... 1 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped
   at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
   ... 7 more
```

I have also got other exceptions when including flow ids in p:commandButton action, which work in h:commandButton.

Thanks.

Edit: I'm using PF version 5.2.6.

Comment: Why don't you tell the PF version? Have you verified if PF version in question is JSF 2.2 compatible? Have you tried latest PF version to exclude an already fixed bug from being the cause?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. That's important :-) I am using last PF, version 5.2.6. (I'm P.F. Elite user). About if it is compatible with JSF 2.2, in 5.2 Guide it states that it is but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Okay. I don't know off top of head either, it was just to exclude one and other. Answer should be sought in PF source code and/or open issues :) But given that you're an elite user, why not just ask them directly?

Comment: @BalusC: Elite yours have access to the z releases in an x.y.z numbering scheme. They do not have direct support. That is for Pro users only